# How to use tar to compress only two files in a directory?

Tags: tar, compression

I'm trying to compress only two files in a directory. Let's say I have a directory named 'images'. In the directory, I have a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg, and d.jpg. I like to compress only a.jpg and b.jpg using tar.

I googled about it, but weirdly I could not find it!

Comment: found out: 

tar cvfz file.tar.gz a.jpg b.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe:

`tar cvf output.tar images/{a,b}.jpg`

?